# HTTP 414 - RESTful and GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, restful-url

Im trying to send a large amount of data using a GET request which is naturally leading to the HTTP 414 URI too long error. The RESTful server I am communicating with is not under my control and I can therefor not send it it via POST as the server will not allow this.

Is there any way around this such that I can still send the same amount of data over in a GET request?

Comment: Depends on the API, but a good API won’t let you create resources using a GET request, and if there’s a data limit on POST requests then that same data limit would probably apply to GET requests too.

Comment: I think GET method is designed to **get** data, use POST/PUT/PATCH to **send** data instead.

Comment: @hwding as it is a RESTful service it only allows GET requests i.e I cannot use POST

Comment: The fact it's a RESTful service has nothing to do with whether or not GET or POST is available (although as others have said, it sounds quite badly designed if you're forced to use a GET operation to store data). That aside, there's nothing you as the consumer of the API can do to avoid this problem. The data is simply too large for the API to accept. Either the API must have it's logic changed to accommodate the volume of data you're trying to send, or you need to send less data per request - which itself would probably require the API to change.

Comment: I think this issue is hard to solve since you need to send large amount of data encoded in the URL which is the only way to send them through GET method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kieran, the answer is no. GET method, as per HTTP standard, does not allow a body as part of the request. You only have the URI to pass data. You're going to need to break your request into a series of smaller requests and group your results afterwards. You'll need to approach this problem with it's asynchronous nature in mind - you might want to look into promises to help you ensure that you've gathered **all** the results from a series of requests.